# Zip/Map functions ending when shortest list runs out

Tags: functions, common-lisp, dash.el

I wanted a function in the style of `zip`, but rather than stopping when one of the supplied lists runs out, I wanted it to continue using `zip` on the rest of the lists.

Looking around at a few Emacs functions (referring mainly to those internal to Emacs and in the Common Lisp, and `dash.el` extensions), I found a few functions like `mapcar*`, `-zip`, and `-zip-fill` that were close to what I was looking for, but ended when one of the given lists ran out.

I ended up writing my own function, but I'm interested in knowing why many of the functions I saw implement this behavior.  Looking [online](http://jessepollak.me/whats-up-with-zip/), it appears that this is the most common interpretation of how `zip` should work.

Would my desired function be considered `zip`?  I figure it may be called something else, unless is a specialized unnamed variant.

To hopefully clarify myself some, here is the function I wrote:

```
(defun my-zip-alt (&rest lists)
  (when lists
    (cons (mapcar #'car lists)
          (apply #'my-zip-alt (delq nil (mapcar #'cdr lists))))))

;; (my-zip-alt '(1 2 3) '(4 5) '(6) '(nil))
;;=> ((1 4 6 nil) (2 5) (3))
```

Recommendations for making my function simpler or more efficient are welcome, of course :)

Comment: It looks like you are transposing the lists. So how about 'transpose'? Or perhaps 'rotate'?

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/40960/15748

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, they could be called `align` or `alignWith`, as in the [these](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.4.2/docs/Data-Align.html) Haskell package.

`alignWith` takes a function which decides how to combine all the variants of the non-uniform tuples (which arise after you continue when the shortest list ran out):

```
align :: f a -> f b -> f (These a b)
alignWith :: (These a b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b
```

(Here, `f` is to be understood as a functor type constructor, like "list". A list of `a` is a special case of `f a`.)

(Sorry for the answer being in Haskell! but if we are looking for commonly used names for such functions, it shouldn't matter much.)

---

I've also seen another Haskell package implementing the same idea.

In [Apart from "these" package, who else implements zipping that continues after the shortest list in a library?](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3bz9iw/apart_from_these_package_who_else_implements/csrcgji), the other implementation under the name [`zipOr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-or-1.0.0.5/docs/Data-Or.html#v:zipOr) has been brought up.

---

And the version "as in F#" in the post online you have linked has been called `pair` once in a Haskell library: [A safe version of zip which will fail (return `Nothing`) on uneven length lists](http://code.haskell.org/~wren/list-extras/dist/doc/html/list-extras/Data-List-Extras-Pair.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, and good observation!  The function names with `align` seem kinda odd to me, and I can see why they didn't come up in my research (Emacs "alignment" usually concerns text spacing within the buffer).  Personally, I prefer a name more like `zip-continue` or something for Emacs, but the Haskell you provided gives me more info to consider.